# Programmatic access to application context and context locations

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext, spring-test

I have some tests (I didn't write them, I am maintaining them) that use the spring ContextConfiguration annotation to supply application contexts:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "testCustomContext.xml" })
public class MyTest  {
}
```

Anyway, a couple of questions.  I am not so familiar with spring custom context locations that don't specify file:/ or classpath:/.  What does it mean?  There are a lot of resources on this test class path with that name.  Are they all loaded?  If not, how does Spring know which to load?

Second, is there a way to programmatically access a spring context that has been wired in this way?

I.e. is there a static Spring Class or ThreadLocal variable that would give me access to the current context?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can gain access to application context by just autowiring it inside test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    // class body...
}
```

As for your second question:

> I am not so familiar with spring custom context locations that don't
>   specify file:/ or classpath:/. What does it mean? There are a lot of
>   resources on this test class path with that name. Are they all loaded?
>   If not, how does Spring know which to load?

From Java Docs:

> A plain path — for example, "context.xml" — will be treated as a
>   classpath resource that is relative to the package in which the
>   specified class is defined.  A path  starting with a slash is treated
>   as an absolute classpath location,  for example:
>   "/org/springframework/whatever/foo.xml".  A path which references a
>   URL (e.g., a path prefixed with classpath:,  file:, http:, etc.) will
>   be added to the results unchanged.

You can learn about Spring `Resources` in docs: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html

Also JavaDocs for `@ContextConfiguration` can give you more knowledge.

I encourage you to study Spring Docs.